# Auto-Format in TextBox Only

Tags: asp.net, formatting

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2010. (Also SQL Management Studio for my database but this information may not be needed, just trying to give enough to make sure what i am doing is understood)

I am making a website in ASP.NET with Visual Basic.net code behind.

The site is basically a contact list site.

> 3 Text Box Fields. First Name, Last Name, Main Phone #.
>
> Add Record Button (Takes the information from the text boxes and inserts into a database)
>
> GridView that shows the database that is being populated with the information

I want to be able to type in for example a 10 digit number and as you type in the number... in the text field you see the formatting...   (999) 999-9999. I do not want the user to have to put the hypens or parenthesis... just the number.

The number is then taken and added to a database but i only want the number 9999999999 to be sent to the database.

I hope it is understood that when I say 9999999999 I actually mean whatever telephone number the user inputs.

I also have a GridView that Visual Studio has and I inserted that. After this my next step will be taking that raw number and putting formatting for visual purposes in the GridView. But my question for now is how to do the formatting only in the text field and to only pass to SQL the 10 digit number without formatting.

I hope I was clear. I am new to all of this actually. I saw something called AJAX.. don't know if I need it.

First time on this site. Any and all help is apprecaited. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the MaskEdit.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx

Comment: Awesome, that is exactly the answer to the question. thanks so much

Comment: @patcho258 No problem, my plesure to help. Because you are new here (from what you say) I like to remind you that if an answer help you, you need to mark it as answer.

Comment: ok great. Thanks again for the help. I will be posting one more question about Gridview also. Hopefully my description below describes in detail for newbies to this like me.. lol.

Comment: I also found these sites. (http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx) (http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_MaskedEdit.ashx).

Thanks again!